# How to start frontend & backend debugging at the same time with intellij?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

I'm trying to set up a run configuration to start Javascript debug & debug of my frontend at the same time. It is possible to start both debug sessions manually and it works. But I have to do this after every change.

It would be nice to have them both restarted in debug mode. I can set the server to run before the js debug in the run config, but this waits until the server is stopped to start the js debug. 
I also tried to set an npm config. This works because I use pm2 to start the server in background, but not in debug mode.

Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using **Node.js** run configuration to start your server, you can use **Browser/Live Edit** tab to start client-side debugging on starting your server: just specify your application URL there and check both **After launch** and **with JavaScript debugger** options

[image]

If you start your server with NPM script, your only option is using the [Multirun](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7248-multirun) plugin for running both `npm start` and **JavaScript Debug** run configurations concurrently

[image]